# Register new client ID procedure stucked

Tags: instagram

Instagram: I would like to register a new client ID (my first) and I'm asked to first verify my phone number so I enter my mobile phone number and a few seconds after I receive a SMS with a 6-digit code. I enter the code into the window and press enter but that only brings me back to the page that asks med to verify my phone number.

I have tried several times with the same result.

Can anyone give me a clue on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Finally!

The issue is with the text input that's asking for your phone number.  Remove the "+1" that precedes your phone number, so the format should just be "3335559999".  When I did this, I successfully created a new client.

Hope this helps.